# Visual Studio 2015 Community 2015 Renew licence failed

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, licensing

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community edition with all of its packages. It presented me a dialog box like on the 30th day saying that the developer licence had expired. When i try renewing the licence using the link on the Dialog with my official paid Microsoft developer account, it says "Failed to download new licence". Tried using several other accounts but no use. Kindly help me out i am stuck completely. The Visual Studio has all of its packages so i do not want to remove it and reinstall.
Please help.

Comment: did you try installing update 1 for visual studio 2015